# Remove duplicate rows that are newer on pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am new to pentaho but I need to remove a duplicate row that is the newest, I tried to [sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ybs5.png) on the colum that I want to check for duplicates and on the date of that row (ascending) and than remove this row using [unique rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfqQY.png). This works like a charm but it does not seem to check for the dates.

How can I Remove the rows that are newer and have a double number?
[image: sort]

[image: unique rows]

[image: the current flow]

Comment: Pentaho is a visual program. Just up voted this question so you can post images!

Comment: Thank you! the links are pictures of the sorting function, the unique rows function and the current flow.  I now added the pictures underneath te post

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it worked, but the datefield that I wanted to sort on was still a String (because is had to extract it as a string from the excel file). I used the str2date function to convert it into a real date and that solved the problem, thanks!